# Generalizations of Bell's inequality to quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, bells-inequality

Can anyone refer me to some sources on generalizations of Bell's inequalities to quantum field theory (as opposed to quantum mechanics)? Scalar fields would be enough.

Comment: Hi -- this question is a bit open-ended, and may be closed.  Please refer to the FAQ for the kinds of questions that are encouraged:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: There is no difference--- the field theory states corresponding to spinning particles are sufficient, and identical at low energy to the ordinary Bell states.

Comment: Check out Tsirelson's problem: http://qig.itp.uni-hannover.de/qiproblems/Bell_inequalities_and_operator_algebras

Answer (score 1):

Read the papers (and recent references citing them) by S. J. Summers and R. Werner in 1987: "Bell's Inequalities and Quantum Field Theory. I. General Setting," Journal of Mathematical Physics 28: 2440-2447, 1987; "Bell's Inequalities and Quantum Field Theory. II. Bell's Inequalities are Maximally Violated," Journal of Mathematical Physics 28: 2448-2456, 1987; "Maximal Violation of Bell's Inequalities is Generic in Quantum Field Theory," Communications in Mathematical Physics 110: 247-259, 1987.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate more?